# Can't sample all conditions for each participant -- strategies to compensate?

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, multiple-comparisons

I am attempting to design a study using Category Comparison Rating / Double Stimulus Comparison Scale to evaluate participant perception of different stimulus conditions.  The original study design was 3x2, within subjects, counterbalanced by randomizing condition order. The conditions are all categorical (eg: participant is asked to rate how much they enjoy `[Apples, Bananas, Cherries]` when served with `[ Milk, Water ]`, relative to every other possible combination).

I've been asked to expand this to 4x2x2 conditions (adding a new condition, and also adding a new axis, essentially, by varying another aspect of the stimulus). It's clear that I can't exhaustively sample this space for each participant in reasonable time.  So, in the toy example, I've been asked to compare `[Apples, Bananas, Cherries, Dates]` x `[Water, Milk]` x `[Warm Room, Cool Room]` (or something, conditions obviously obfuscated but hopefully that gets the idea across).  This is already a time-intensive study, and I have a relatively small pool of participants, so I accept that statistical power is likely to be low, but I'd like to get the most value possible given the constraints.

I can see that there are at least two possible ways to achieve this:

- Randomly present each participant with some subset of all possible condition-pairs, and accept less data about each pair for better overall coverage
- Select a subset of conditions ahead of time and present that same subset, in randomly counterbalanced order, to all participants (no data about some pairs, but more data about the remaining pairs)

How should I approach this to maximize the validity of the results?

Comment: Try searching for incomplete block design and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you @mdewey. That is a very useful search term for this context!

Comment: Given your updated understanding of the subject based on @mdewey , could you clarify your question?